# How to get values from an option being selected

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a Users table that has User_id, Firstname, Lastname, and Role. I like to create a classic ASP page to display values when an option is selected. Whenever I select a username from the drop-down box, then it displays its values below. I tried that but it didn't do anything when I select a username in the drop-down.

```
Here is my code:
User_id   Firstname   Lastname   Role
-------------------------------------
1         Jenny       Rogers     A
2         Jenny2      Rogers2    B
1         Jenny       Rogers     B
2         Jenny2      Rogers2    A
3         Jenny3      Rogers3    C
```

ASP code:

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="newMenu" name="frmReport" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <strong>New User: </strong>
          <select name="UserID">
            <option value="">All Users</option>
            <% sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT User_id, Lastname, Firstname FROM User "
                    objRS.Open sSQL, objConn
                    Do Until objRS.EOF
                        Response.Write("<option value='" & objRS("User_id") & "'>" & objRS("Lastname") & ", " & objRS("Firstname") & "</option>")
                    objRS.MoveNext
                    Loop
                    objRS.Close
                %>
          </select>
          <% 
            If Len("UserID") > 0 Then
                                    sSQL = "SELECT User_id, Role FROM Users WHERE User_id = '" & request.Form("UserID") & "' ; "
                                    objRS.Open sSQL, objConn
                    Do Until objRS.EOF
                %>
            <input type="text" name="Role" value="<%= objRS(" Role ") %>">
            <%  objRS.MoveNext
                    Loop
                    objRS.Close
    End If
                %>
              <input type="hidden" name="FormSource" value="SubmitForm">
              <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
              </th>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Instead posting the asp, could you please post the results of the asp.

Comment: You can't change the ASP and SQL query based on the selection without additional requests. You can either load all the data into a json and use the select to filter, or make ajax requests on change.

Comment: Currently I have 1 table only. How do I load all data into a join and use the select to filter? Thanks.

Comment: I think the point @Daniel is trying to make is that classic ASP is server side code, ie it's executed on the server when the page loads.  Nothing on your page will change until you submit the form.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you want

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!--#include file="Connections/BUYIN.asp" -->
<%
''''''Recordset with Names
Dim objRS
Dim objRS_cmd
Dim objRS_numRows

Set objRS_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
objRS_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_BUYIN_STRING
objRS_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName FROM dbo.BI_Users WHERE firstname like '%test%'" 
objRS_cmd.Prepared = true

Set objRS = objRS_cmd.Execute
objRS_numRows = 0
%>
<!--Results -->
<% If Request.Form("selectID") <> "" Then %>
<%
Dim rsResults__getID
rsResults__getID = "0"
If (Request.Form("selectID") <> "") Then 
  rsResults__getID = Request.Form("selectID")
End If
%>
<%
Dim rsResults
Dim rsResults_cmd
Dim rsResults_numRows

Set rsResults_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsResults_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_BUYIN_STRING
rsResults_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, fkRoleID FROM dbo.BI_Users WHERE id = ?" 
rsResults_cmd.Prepared = true
rsResults_cmd.Parameters.Append rsResults_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 5, 1, -1, rsResults__getID) ' adDouble

Set rsResults = rsResults_cmd.Execute
rsResults_numRows = 0
%>
<% End If %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="testasp2.asp">
<select name="selectID" id="selectID">
    <%
While (NOT objRS.EOF)
%>
    <option value="<%=(objRS.Fields.Item("id").Value)%>" <%If (Not isNull(Request.Form("selectID"))) Then If (CStr(objRS.Fields.Item("id").Value) = CStr(Request.Form("selectID"))) Then Response.Write("selected=""selected""") : Response.Write("")%> ><%=(objRS.Fields.Item("LastName").Value)%></option>
    <%
  objRS.MoveNext()
Wend
If (objRS.CursorType > 0) Then
  objRS.MoveFirst
Else
  objRS.Requery
End If
%>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
<hr />
<% If Request.Form("selectID") <> "" Then %>
<% If Not rsResults.EOF Or Not rsResults.BOF Then %>
<p><%=(rsResults.Fields.Item("id").Value)%> </p>
<p><%=(rsResults.Fields.Item("FirstName").Value)%> </p>
<p><%=(rsResults.Fields.Item("LastName").Value)%> </p>
<p><%=(rsResults.Fields.Item("fkRoleid").Value)%> </p>

<%
rsResults.Close()
Set rsResults = Nothing
%>
<% End If %>
<% Else %>
<%= "No Results Yet" %>
<% End If  %>
</body>
</html>
<%
objRS.Close()
Set objRS = Nothing
%>
```